# Error using subliminal python

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/subliminal", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3080, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3066, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3093, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 952, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'argparse' distribution was not found and is required by stevedore
```

Getting this error when using subliminal. Can you please suggest a suitable solution?

Comment: Describe what `subliminal` is please? Also, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gabriel apparently it is this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/subliminal  I haven't heard of it before.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the 'stevedore' package.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stevedore/+bug/1401783

It has been fixed already, but that was after Ubuntu 15.10 was released.

---

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stevedore/+bug/1401783/comments/5

> Unfortunately the fix is not yet backported to vivid or wily. To fix it yourselves you need to remove argparse from the following file:
>
> vivid: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.3.0.egg-info/requires.txt
>
> wily: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.5.0.egg-info/requires.txt

Comment: Good answer (even with so little information given), very poor question. +1

Comment: Indeed.  The question would be better suited for askubuntu, but a quick google search on the error message turned up the bug report in launchpad.